# "administrate"/"manage" vs "maintain"/"support" for someone in an assistant role

Tags: business-language

What is a softer term for the completion of tasks assigned to a junior/assistant employee that involve administering or managing a system or process? For example, they may be asked to "manage a schedule" or "administrate access rights". I feel that those terms lend too much decision-making responsibility to that role, when it is more of a maintenance, support, or data-entry task.

Am I wrong? Is this demeaning? And is there a third option somewhere in-between?

Comment: You haven't voted or commented on the two answers below. Were either helpful at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **perform** as a neutral term.

- To add responsibility to the role, add *without supervision*.
- To reduce it, add *under supervision*.

Definition and Usage of **perform**, in [American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perform):

> 1. To begin and carry through to completion; do: *The surgeon **performed** the operation.*
> 2. To take action in accordance with the requirements of; fulfill: ***perform*** one's contractual obligations.

Comment: This is good.  For variety you can also say ***carry out***.  Once in a while ***conduct*** works too.  You can also say ***assist with _______*** and ***provide support for ______***.

Answer (score 0):

I've always preferred the term **"[Administrative Assistant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/administrative%20assistant)"** for entry-level positions and **"[Administrative Analyst](http://agency.governmentjobs.com/saccity/default.cfm?action=viewclassspec&ClassSpecID=33565)"** for more advanced positions. Relative to your specific questions, Administrative Assistant tasks can include "keeping (or maintaining) a schedule (or calendar)" and "monitoring access rights" in addition to "providing maintenance, support, and data-entry."

> **Administrative Assistant**: "a person whose job is to support an executive, group, department, or organization especially by handling administrative tasks (such as data entry, correspondence, filing, and scheduling appointments)." Merriam-Webster Dictionary

versus

> **Administrative Analyst**: "Under general direction, the Administrative Analyst performs professional-level duties in one or more internal support areas, including budget, finance, personnel, contracts and grants, procurement, or other assignments supporting the mission of the organization; compiles and analyzes data; participates in design and implementation of systems and procedures." City of Sacramento, California